# Issues with AVRISP MKII programmer

Tags: spi, microchip, attiny, avrdude

I am trying to program ATtiny10 using AVRISP MKII programmer and AVRDUDESS, spend 2 days trying to flash it but had no luck. Now I came up with a few issues regarding AVRISP MKII programmer, which might be the cause.

*First:* I tried connecting to chip using Microchip studio software, I successfully connected to AVRISP and measured voltage on Vcc pin correctly (Around +5V) which I provide from external source to ATtiny10, but what is weird, when I disconnect the source, Microchip studio still manages to read the voltage and after measuring it with multimeter on Vcc pin of a programmer, I still read +5V, shouldn't this pin be input to sense, when mcu is connected? Why does mine provide voltage instead of reading it?

*Second:* I know that ATtiny10 should be programmed via special interface called TPI (Tiny Programmable Interface) which consists of 3 lines (Reset, CLK and Data). AVRISP MKII datasheet states that I should use Vcc, GND, RESET, CLK and MISO pins when programming in TPI interface. So does this mean that data to ATtiny and from ATtiny comes from single line? Does the programmer knows, that I am trying to program in TPI interface and it automatically switches from spi to TPI when I select ATtiny10 chip?

Comment: Start more simply: can you read the device ID? If not, you have a communication problem. What is the AVRdude error message? MkII should support TPI: https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-BEB648AA-8539-418A-9EFB-118BDC9DC77B-en-US-1/index.html?GUID-F9EFD3A0-7172-4C06-BFDE-D1D21A33A9F7

Comment: In  Microchip Studio next ---> Tools---->Device Programming. Select AVRISP mkII in the Tool drop-down list and select Attiny10 in the Device list.  TPI will come up in the Interface list by default, next click 'Apply'. And now you can program Attinny10.  Go to --->memories and select your project's .hex file. Then click 'Program'.  And you're done.  Also, sometimes a reset of a programmer is needed, simply to reset the programmer all you need is to unplug it from USB and then reconnect it.

Comment: I tried reading the device ID to make sure that everything is OK, no programming, no memory reading, just see if pc can see ATtiny10 and well got errors. Connections are good, signals are coming to correct pins, so I guess the problem is with microcontrollers, although, I have tried a few of them, and all seem to have same problem.